# Can a broker cancel market orders?

Tags: stock-markets, brokerage, market-order

I sold my Tesla shares through the Revolut app. After I confirmed this, the transaction was in a "pending" state for several hours. After a few hours, I received a notification telling me that the transaction had been canceled due to technical issues on their partner’s side related to the execution of transactions. Meanwhile, Tesla shares fell $90 per share. Can they do it? Can I apply for compensation?

Comment: You would need to look closely at Revolut's Ts&Cs, but the chances are there's some kind of clause about them only needing to make a "best effort" to execute your instructions.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer here is probably "don't use a crap broker"  :/

Answer (score 1):

If an order is pending and in a stuck state, you can call them and ask them to cancel it.  If they can't, and you lose money as a result of their incompetence then there would be a valid claim for damages.

Similarly, if an order should go straight to an exchange but doesn't when it should you could have a similar claim.  However there are valid reasons why an order may not go to an exchange.  Some firms do not execute orders outside of trading hours.  Firms may also reject orders based on various criteria (it is a regulatory requirement).

In the first instance, you can ask them what happened and why it didn't execute.

If discussions with them are not successful, go to their regulator.

While most contracts will try to absolve them of any liability, there are usually limits to limitation of liability.

Comment: I think OP wanted the order to execute, but it was canceled *by the broker*. You're describing a case where the customer wants to cancel.

Comment: This happened to me a few times in 20 years. The order gets stuck somewhere on the transmission path. You want execution but it's not that easy. The trading desk has to verify if the order was  executed (it's a platform technology issue not clearing the order after execution) or if unfilled and stuck. When this happened to me, the after verifying non fill, the tech team then worked to cancel the stuck order.  At that point, it was up to me whether to place the order again at changed prices. There's usually little recourse because you sign away a lot of your rights when opening your account.